# Yii2. Button jumps on next line after Pjax wrap added

Tags: button, yii2, containers, pjax

I use Yii2. I have 3 buttons in one line.[image]
If I wrap for example the last one into the Pjax it jumps to next line.[image]
How to correct the Pjax css class to avoid such jump?

```
Pjax::begin(['id' => 'pjax'.$model->id]);
                    echo Html::button('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></span><span id ="projectbadge'.$model->id.'" class="badge badge-notify">'.count($model->votes).'</span>', [
                            'value' => Url::to(['project/votes', 'id'=>$model->id]),
                            'class' => 'linkbutton',
                            'id'=>'projectVotes'.$model->id,
                            'data-toggle'=>'tooltip',
                            'title'=> 'Votes',
                            'onfocus' => 'blur();'
                         ]);
                    Pjax::end();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `Pjax` uses a `div` so you can set the style to `inline`

```
Pjax::begin(['id' => 'pjax', 'options' => ['style' => 'display: inline;']]);
```

or if you're on 2.0.7+ you can change the tag

```
Pjax::begin(['id' => 'pjax', 'options' => ['tag' => 'span']]);
```